# loading local files in django

Tags: django, image, django-admin

I have a folder in `c:\images`, images here are updated by another app. Then I wanted a Django application to read those images on the admin site. The django applicationis sitting in `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\myapp` I have tried adding below lines in **settings.py**

```
CURRENT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(CURRENT_PATH, '../../images').replace('\\','/')

MEDIA_URL = 'images/'
```

I also tried including the whole path in django admin as below in **admin.py**

```
def img_field(self, obj):
    return format_html('<img src="{}" width="500" height="500" />'.format("c:\images\phot1.png"))
```

If i put online image link it works fine as below:

```
def img_field(self, obj):
  img = "https://www.thebalancesmb.com/thmb/5G9LJXyFzbTVS-Fj_32sHcgJ8lU=/3000x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc():format(webp)/start-online-business-with-no-money-4128823-final-5b87fecd46e0fb00251bb95a.png"
  return format_html('<img src="{}" width="500" height="500" />'.format(img))
```

How can i get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it I just needed to add the below lines in urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [ 
  #urls here      
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

It is working fine.